# Autocomplete import paths WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I have a `create-react-app` and I have `NODE_PATH = src/` in my `.env` file to make import paths of common components simpler. But WebStorm isn't recognizing it and wont autocomplete any of them like it does if I were to `import ../../Common/foo` or how it autocompletes node modules `import Button from 'material-ui/Button` always gives me a long list of material-ui components and helps make sure I don't have any typos.

Is there a way I can configure this in WebStorm?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `NODE_PATH` in default **Node.js** run configuration to get it respected - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19476#comment=27-1255547:

- in `Run | Edit configurations`, expand **Defaults** node, select **Node.js**
- in default **Node.js** run configuration, press ellipsis button next to **Environment variables:** field
- add `NODE_PATH` variable there, specify a full path to `src` folder as a value
- in **Project** tool window, mark `src` folder as **Resource root**
- reopen the project

Comment: Thanks, I saw that post, but I think that is just making you able to write out `app/component/foo` instead of `../../../app/component/foo` and not actually telling webstorm to autocomplete typing it. At least I didn't notice anything when setting it